# Promise.all(), map() with callback function gives 404 error on .catch (err => {}) in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Promise.all(), map() with callback function gives 404 error on .catch (err => {}) in Reactjs.

I could call the endpoint and get the response but end up by getting the below 404 error on the callback.
**error request failed with status code 404 at createerror**

Any suggestion how this logic should be handled.

Note: If I remove the query parameter from Axios (+ '?nbr=' + data.id) it works fine.... !!??

```js
useEffect(() => {
 const url_endpoint = `${url}/getData`
 if (data != null) {
            Promise.all(
               data.map(async (data) =>
               Axios.get(url_endpoint + '?nbr=' + data.id, {
            headers: {
               timestamp: 1111
            }
         })
            .then(response => {
               const { data } = response
               if (response.status) {
                  responseCode = response.status
               }
               setLog({ 'status': 'success'})
               callback({ error: false, data })
            })
            .catch(err => {
               if (err.response) {
                  responseCode = err.response.status
               }
               setLog({'status': 'error'})
               error({ 'responseCode': responseCode })
               callback({ APIError: true })
            })
            )
      }
      }, [])
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Avoid the 404 error?

Comment: Yes.. I want to avoid error & access the response. ty.

Comment: Use your dev tools (particularly the network tab) to figure out what's going on. We can't generally figure out 404 errors.

Comment: Well, if the server responds with a 404 error, then that's what you've got. You have to fix either the client or the server to allow successful requests between them. Btw, you *can* read the 404 response, I don't think that's what you want though.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `Promise.allSettled()`

> The `Promise.allSettled()` method returns a promise that resolves *after all of the given promises have either fulfilled or rejected*, with an array of objects that each describes the outcome of each promise.

```js
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(reject, 100, 'foo'));
const promises = [promise1, promise2];

Promise.allSettled(promises).
  then((results) => results.forEach((result) => console.log(result.status)));

// expected output:
// "fulfilled"
// "rejected"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried the Promise.allSettled() but not working.. i see issue in the promise tied with map function which passes value id for the url parameter, that throws the error. If I pass the url simply like    Axios.get(url_endpoint) then I dont see issue.......

Comment: @br0526 Could you try to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)? _axios.get(\`${url_endpoint}?nbr=${data.id}\`)_